# Specifying the conditional distribution for the response in practice?

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, modeling

In normal linear regression, defining $Y_i = X_i\beta+\epsilon_i,$ with $\epsilon_i$ c.i.i.d. $\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$, is equivalent to say $Y|X \sim \mathcal{N}_n(X\beta,\sigma^2I_n)$. The second seems a better choice for generalization, for instance in GLM's, where the distribution of $Y|X$ usually belongs to the exponential family.

In practice, if there are no "physical constraints" in choosing the statistical model, how does one model the stochastic part of a GLM? I used to think that you could do it by looking at the histogram of $Y$, but this question [What if residuals are normally distributed, but y is not?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12262/what-if-residuals-are-normally-distributed-but-y-is-not) made me realize I was completely wrong!